# How to calculate mean in different columns in R

Tags: r, mean

I have a painfully simple question. Due to small sample sizes I want to group several species for analysis. I am trying to make a new variable which has calculated the means of columns 13, 15, 16 and 17.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

to compute the mean of a column, just call the colMeans function, eg to get the mean of the **first** column in the following dataframe example:

```
df <- data.frame(rnorm(4),rnorm(4),rnorm(4))
meanFirstCol <- colMeans(df[1])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think you misunderstood (my fault). I meant across columns rather than within.

Comment: I think this works: mean(cbind(df[,13], df[,15:17])) even though it is not elegant